# Preventing diagonal movement

Tags: java, movement

I was originally fine with diagonal movement but it's clashing with my sprite animation...

```
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    switch(key){
        case KeyEvent.VK_W:{
            dir = 3;
            velY = -speed;
            break;
        }
        case KeyEvent.VK_S:{
            dir = 2;
            velY = speed;
            break;
        }
        case KeyEvent.VK_A:{
            dir = 1;
            velX = -speed;
            break;
        }
        case KeyEvent.VK_D:{
            dir  = 0;
            velX = speed;
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    switch(key){
        case KeyEvent.VK_W:{
            velY = 0;
            break;
        }
        case KeyEvent.VK_S:{
            velY = 0;
            break;
        }
        case KeyEvent.VK_A:{
            velX = 0;
            break;
        }
        case KeyEvent.VK_D:{
            velX = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
}

    public void update(){
    y += velY;
    x += velX;
}
```

I thought that perhaps a switch statement or an if else statement would prevent multiple keys from firing at once, but it's not working out. I even tried synchronizing some methods but still to no avail. Any suggestions? And please ignore the dir variable I use it to find the direction the player is facing.

Comment: If you press A then `velX` gets set to non-zero, and then if you press S after that without letting go of A, `velY` gets set to non-zero, so you get diagonal movement. If you want to stop moving in Y when someone presses A or D, then you need to set `velY` to 0 when you set `velX` to non-0, and vice versa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obtaining multiple key presses can be found in this answer: [How do I handle multiple key presses in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752999/how-do-i-handle-multiple-key-presses-in-java)

Assign each one to a boolean variable and then check each key and add to the movement vector. Opposite keys will cancel out, and you can also test whether a key is already in use based on that.

```
if(noDiagonal)
{
    velX = 0;
    velY = 0;

    if(keyLeft) velX += -1;
    if(keyRight) velX += 1;

    if(velX == 0)
    {
        if(keyUp) velY += -1;
        if(keyDown) velY += 1;
    }
}
else // In case you change your mind...
{
    velX = 0;
    velY = 0;

    if(keyLeft) velX += -1;
    if(keyRight) velX += 1;
    if(keyUp) velY += -1;
    if(keyDown) velY += 1;

    // Normalize to prevent high speed diagonals
    float length = sqrt((velX * velX ) + (velY * velY ));
    velX = velX/length;
    velY = velY/length;
}
velX *= speed;
velY *= speed;
```

Pick which animation/direction to use based on the speed in that direction, rather than the key. This will make it easier to handle automatic animation later (like in a cutscene), or you can turn that part off individually (like if they're standing on a conveyer belt).

Comment: Thank you for this much more dynamic and versatile way of handling movement and forgive me for such a late reply!