# How to avoid movement speed stacking when multiple keys are pressed?

Tags: unity, javascript, movement

I've started a new game which requires no mouse, thus leaving the movement up to the keyboard. I have tried to incorporate 8 directions; up, left, right, up-right and so on. However when I press more than one arrow key, the movement speed stacks (http://gfycat.com/CircularBewitchedBarebirdbat). How could I counteract this?

Here is relevant part of my code:

```
var speed : int = 5;

function Update () {
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    } else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)) {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    } else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(315, Vector3.up);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow)) {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: tangent: The indentation in your code was a little messed up so I didn't notice at first, but the conditions in your code will prevent most of it from running. Like, if(UpArrow) else if(UpArrow && RightArrow) will never run the 'else' branch.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Separate your direction selection code from actual movement code.

1. Choose `Direction` by checking which keys are pressed. Store it as a unit (normalized) vector.
2. Multiply your `Direction` with `Speed` and with `DeltaTime`.
3. Apply resulting transform to your object/camera.

Answer (score 28):

You need to take the sum of the directions, normalize that, then multiply by the speed.

I tangentially answered this as part of my response to [Preventing diagonal movement](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/80131/preventing-diagonal-movement/80137#80137)

Specifically:

```
velX = 0;
velY = 0;

if(keyLeft) velX += -1;
if(keyRight) velX += 1;
if(keyUp) velY += -1;
if(keyDown) velY += 1;

// Normalize to prevent high speed diagonals
length = sqrt((velX * velX ) + (velY * velY ));
if (length != 0)
{
    velX /= length;
    velY /= length;
}

velX *= speed;
velY *= speed;
```

Comment: Heheh, Larry would be proud!
http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LazinessImpatienceHubris

Comment: Note that Unity already provides methods to get the [magnitude](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-magnitude.html) and [squared magnitude](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-sqrMagnitude.html) of a Vector.

Comment: This produces NaN if no keys are pressed

Comment: @jzx Indeed, we strive to be like the fabled Hobbits. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G49RUPv5-NU

Answer (score 11):

The "normalized direction vector" is how this task is usually approached, and how I often do it, but lately I've simply been clamping the resulting movement vector. It usually achieves the same end result and the code is a lot simpler:

```
var moveSpeed = 6.0f;
function Update() {
  var movement = Vector3.zero;
  movement.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * moveSpeed;
  movement.z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * moveSpeed;
  movement = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(movement, moveSpeed);
  movement *= Time.deltaTime;
  transform.Translate(movement);
}
```

Simpler code is almost always better :E

Comment: What does `ClampMagnitude` do, isn't it the same code as `Normalize * Constant` in disquise?

Comment: Not quite. "Clamping" a value makes sure it stays within a range/below the maximum, while normalizing sets the value to a constant. With Unity at least, GetAxis() returns slightly accelerating values, giving you a smoother movement. Normalizing the vector overrides that acceleration, while clamping allows the acceleration to happen. It's subtle but looks nicer. The end effect is pretty much the same though.

Comment: +1 for being the only answer written directly in the context of Unity. The API provides all kinds of useful Vector/Quaternion math methods with this sort of situation in mind, no reason to roll your own.

Comment: I'd clamp to 1 and only multiply with `moveSpeed` after clamping and possibly merge it with the multiplication by `deltaTime`.

Comment: Does that change gain more than just removing one multiplication operation? Like, does clamping 1 operate differently from clamping 6? wondering what your change does...

Comment: It's about decoupling, not performance or different behaviour. I view computing the input direction and how the game reacts to it as different concerns. So I'd probably split this into two functions even, one `GetInputDirection` and then one that computes the movement. (And don't forget to use @nickname for notifications)

Comment: Wouldn't this still allow faster acceleration if you press more keys (with a clamped max speed)?

Comment: Acceleration, yes I believe so. But that's still better than NO acceleration, since the effect is so quick anyway.

Comment: @jhocking Thanks for the sample code. Worked as intended, however I hoped to rotate the player (http://gfycat.com/CircularBewitchedBarebirdbat) so that when I shoot it'll shoot in the direction facing. Any way that I could incorporate this?

Comment: transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(movement);